# I need a script in python (random number)

Tags: events, random

Hi my script is a simple one

```
"block load 

{

    es_msg #multi #green [Disconnect Info] #defaulthas been loaded.

}

block unload

{

    es_msg #multi #green [Disconnect Info] #defaulthas been unloaded.

}

event player_connect

{

    if (event_var(networkid) == BOT) do 

    {
    es_msg #multi #lightgreen event_var(name) #default
Has connected from #lightgreenCanda .#default

    }

    else do

    {

    }
}   

event player_disconnect

{

    if (event_var(networkid) == BOT) do

    {

        es_msg #multi Player: #lightgreen [ event_var(name) ]
 #default SteamID: #green [ **STEAM_0:1:03462187** ] #default has disconnected.

    }

    else do
    {
    es_msg #multi Player: #lightgreen [ event_var(name) ] 
*#default SteamID: #green [ event_var(networkid) ] #default has disconnected.*

    }

}"
```

My need is her [ STEAM_0:1:03462187 ] to be [ STEAM_0:1:random# ]

I try with import random

random.randrange(00000000, 99999999)
Not work, tell my unknown command "import",

my script is text file.
I think i need a .py file and i don't know to create one. 
I'm a machinist not a programer
The script i use in a server game with eventscripts.

Thank you .

Comment: You are using something besides python. I don't know what is, as it doesn't match anything I've seen before. Without knowing what you are actually using we can't help you.

Answer (score 4):

That's not python, it's eventscript.

Try creating a variable, then using:

```
es_rand <name of variable> 1 99999999
```

And then printing that variable instead of the steam ID.